# position sticky inside a container with a parent that has overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a case that produces the following html and css:

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="overflow-hidden">
      <div class="overflow-x-auto">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
          <div>Item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to make this work with position sticky without adding any additional overflow properties to the "container" element? If I remove container it all works, but I cannot remove it as this is the html that is generated by the plugin I am using.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-q8jqs1?file=index.html)

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Instead of a link to an external website, make a working examlpe here with the appropriate functionality

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve / what is the issue? The example you gave is working. When the content is bigger than the 200px div, `sticky` is sticky and the rest is scrolling. Isn't that what you want? Is this the HTML and CSS of the plugin? If so, I don't get the issue.

Comment: @jessman5 it does not remain sticky if you scroll to the bottom - so past a certain point the entire content flows outside of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with the code snippet provided, I found the reason:

It's because `container` has `max-height: 100px`. The `sticky` is sticky for exactly these 100px. The content is running down and overflows, because the `overflow` is set on it's parent `overflow-x-auto`. So the max-height also needs to be on the parent. If the inline styling on the `container` comes from the plugin, you'll have to overwrite it.

See example below.

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <div class="overflow-x-auto">
    <div class="container" style="max-height: 100px">
      <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you!